# insert data from .csv file from windows C: drive into oracle11g database

Tags: windows, oracle, csv, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am very new at this, I need to insert .csv file placed on windows C: drive into oracle11g database.
thinking of using sql loader, but not sure where to start.

sorry I don't have any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a target table (if you don't have it):

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sri Tra 21 12:04:48 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table my_table (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
```

Sample data file (as you didn't post yours), named `my_data.csv`, located in a root of my `M` disk (yours is `C`):

```
1,Little
2,Foot
```

Control file (named `test37.ctl`):

```
load data
infile 'm:\my_data.csv'
truncate into table my_table
fields terminated by ','
(id, 
 name
)
```

Run SQL*Loader from operating system command prompt:

```
M:\>sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test37.ctl log=test37.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sri Tra 21 12:08:40 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

M:\>
```

Check what we've done:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sri Tra 21 12:09:15 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from my_table;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot

SQL>
```